# How to design circular step progress indicator in native android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-progressbar

Please help me to achieve step progress indicator as shown below in android. I could not find any relevant library to achieve this.

[image: Text]

Comment: voting for close this question for a reason: _Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more_. Write it by your own, learn, ask question when you stuck on something (which won't be a turorial...)

Answer (score 0):

Create 7 different vector graphics and update them one at a time

Simplest method I know of

Use this link [animated vector](https://youtu.be/scZYIAZrMWk)